# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in angular $location

Tags: angularjs

`$location.path('/user/logout');`

This line gets an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` in console. It goes when that line is commented. What is the wrong with my code pls.

```
angular.module('symphony', ['ngRoute'])

        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $location) {

    $routeProvider
            .when('/user', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/pages/user.php',
        controller: enterpriseController,
    })

            .when('/modules', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/pages/merchant/dash.php',
        controller: merchantController,
    })

             .when('/user/logout', {
        $location.path('/user/logout');
    });


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is raised by the following code:

```
.when('/user/logout', {
    $location.path('/user/logout');
});
```

the second parameter of function `when` is an object, so you can't place `$location.path('/user/logout');` here!

What's your purpose for route `/user/logout`?

====================================

If you need server side to handle route, try this:

```
.when('/user/logout', {
    template: '<div></div>',
    controller: function(){
        window.location.href= "/user/logout";
    }
});
```

Comment: Because all my links are angular routes. So page is not reloaded. But I want to force /user/logout to reload without angular routing.

Comment: @Namal I don't understand why you need do this, you mean this? `.when('/user/logout', {redirectTo: '/user/logout'})` this will surely cause a infinite loop!

Comment: Then can you tell me how to send server request under angular routing without ajax? Because all my current requests are ajax based and normal page requests are disabled by angular.

Comment: you mean when user route to '/user/logout', send a ajax request to server '/user/logout'?

Comment: you mean you need server side to handle '/user/logout', not angular, right? And your server side has template to responsible for this request?

Comment: ya exactly. Now what the happening is angular has replaced my logout request.